# XPage Date/Time - This field is not a valid time

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus

After selecting the date from the date picker in Date/Time field on Xpage, some users getting "This field is not valid time", but others are working fine.

Only few users having this problem, all others are not facing problem with the same Xpage..

What is the cause of this issue? and How can I resolve it?

Comment: It would be great if you could ask your users what browser (including which version) they are using and edit your question to include that. That could give more details on exact cause of the issue.

Comment: One-upped the question because it's important, but more information about which browsers and how they fit with Fredrik's answer in regards to locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the user browser language setting, it as "English (United Kingdom) [en-GB]", So I have changed into "English (United States) [en-US]". Now the Issue has been resolved... :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem occur when you browser is reporting one language but is adding date strings that doesn't match this.
I have seen this problem when using an english Google Chrome with another locale.
then the locale gets mixed up. 
Make sure your OS Locale matches the locale in the webbrowser.
In Chrome this is done in settings "language and input" I think the button is called.
And make sure your locale is added to the list. Drag the locale you want to use to the top.

Another problem could be that you have the setting use "**Server Locale**" in the Domino server document, Domino web engine tab or in the internet site document. The settings is called **Default regional locale**: is set to server locale and not browser accept language. If you have server locale then the language of all your clients must match the servers locale.